# rails not allowing me to call a method from inside another method - rails keeps saying the method is undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, rails-models

In my model for tutoring sessions, I have code that triggers reminder texts at different times.  Everything worked fine, until I tried some refactoring, and now I am having issues.

```
def send_reminder_text(texts_batch)
    texts_batch.each do |text|
        page_number = Refugee.find(text.refugee_id)[:last_page]
        body_of_text = text[:begin_time].in_time_zone.strftime("Burma Reminder: upcoming session at %I:%M%p beginning on page #{page_number}. 
            Please email jek2141@columbia.edu to reschedule or cancel the session.") 
        text.begin_text(body_of_text)
    end
end

def self.deliver_pm_reminder_text
    texts_batch = TutoringSession.batch_for_pm_reminder_text
    send_reminder_text(texts_batch)
end

def self.deliver_just_before_reminder_text
    texts_batch = TutoringSession.batch_for_just_before_reminder_text
    send_reminder_text(texts_batch)
end
```

When I call the `deliver_just_before_reminder_text` function, I get the following error message:

```
irb(main):006:0> TutoringSession.send_reminder_text
NoMethodError: undefined method `send_reminder_text' for #<Class:0x00000003cfe5d8>
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record   /base.rb:1088:in `method_missing'
from (irb):6
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:45:in `start'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

This is in spite of the fact that the `send_reminder_text` is clearly defined above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method declaration specifies that the method is on objects of the `TutoringSession` class:

```
def send_reminder_text(texts_batch)
```

But you're trying to call it as if it were a method on the class itself:

```
irb(main):006:0> TutoringSession.send_reminder_text
```

Try changing your definition to:

```
def self.send_reminder_text(texts_batch)
```